# Rooting A Motorola Droid Razr M Phone on Verizon Network

Tags: rooting, 4.4-kitkat, motorola-droid

I have a Droid Razr M, running on the verizon network. I would like to root this phone so I can use some of the more advanced features of Tasker; however, I am very fearful of "bricking" my phone. I see many approaches, which concerns me, because I would feel more comfortable if I could be sure process X is the one to use and works. Here are the particulars of my phone:

1. Model #: Droid Razr M
2. Android Version: 4.4.2
3. System Version: 183.46.10.XT907.Verizon.en.us
4. Baseband Version: SM_BP_101031.042.32.86P

Can anyone advise me as to the best approach to take, even if it means there is no current software to root my phone with the version it has?

Thanks,
FDijohn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I could comment, I would, but yes, TowelRoot is a safe download. It is one of the most commonly used root methods for newer devices. Neither of the antivirus programs that I use have had any problem with it.

(If someone has the ability to repost this as a comment on @IAmTheSquidward's answer, that would be awesome)

EDIT: Several sites and forums state that it will work on the RAZR M and HD if your build number is `.182` or `.183`. If you already updated to whatever came next, then it is too late and you might not get the chance to root again. Not to be rude, but that's what you get for having a Motorola and/or Verizon phone. They both (along with Samsung) try their hardest to make sure that you cannot root or unlock your phone.

Answer (score 0):

With GeoHot's new Towelroot exploit, it's as easy as installing an .apk and clicking a button.

[Towelroot link](http://towelroot.com)

Just download and install that app, and then run it.  After it's done, go on Google Play and download [SuperSU](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu&hl=en).

Comment: I tried to download from the link above, and McAfee blocked it saying it detected a trojan called: Artemis!E287E785D0E3, and proceeded to delete it. Is Towelroot a safe download?

Comment: Towelroot is "safe" for what it does... Without going in to too much detail, it exploits a flaw in the Linux kernel that Android uses... McAfee is detecting it because of it's malicious code.  You're fine to download it! :)

Comment: Thanks everyone for offering advice. I had one more question, I saw on the LifeHacker site that towelroot does not work on Motorola phones, is that correct? My phone is definitely a Motorola device. Thanks again!

Comment: It works, I've used it on my girlfriend's Moto M...  I don't know why they'd say it doesn't...

Comment: I downloaded the app and run it however it keeps saying towelroot isnt responding, what do i do?